# height: 100% not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a `div` (**Menu**) with a **width of 20%** of my screen and a **height of 100%** but the `div` does not display on the screen. I do not know why. Here is my code:

```css
#Menu {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: black;
    min-width: 20%;
    min-height: 100%
}
 
#Bar {
    float: right;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="Menu">Menu</div>
<div id="Bar">Bar</div>
```

Comment: you tell you CSS to float your `Bar` right and then left o_0?

Comment: This error is because your `div` tags are empty. Put some content and it will work.

Comment: use height;100vh; it's batter ?

Answer (score 0):

Since your `div` elements are empty, they will collapse to 0 height. A height of `100%` does not help in this case.

You will find that you can display your elements if you include a `min-height` property.

I have made some modifications to get it to work, together with some fine-tuning. I always indent my real code, but I have left the modifications un-indented so that you can see them more easily.

```css
#Menu { 
 display:inline-block; 
 background-color : black;
 min-width:20%; 
 min-height:100%;
margin: 0;
min-height:10px;
float: right;
}

#Bar {
 float:right;
 background-color : blue;
 width:80%; 
 height:100%;
 margin:0;
 float:left;
min-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Menu">
  
</div>
<div id="Bar">
 
</div>
```

Comment: "A height of 100% does not help in this case." - Normally it would, though, specifically if the parent element had a height `> 0`.